# How do I redirect one website to another with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know a thing about JavaScript and figured this would be a first take at it.

Reddit changed sorting from **HOT** to **BEST**.

I want to create a Script that on any subreddit, or front page, would switch the sort back to **HOT**.

I looked at this page, but because i have no knowledge, i don't know where to put it

[How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: You can't add a script to a 3rd party website like that.

Comment: I think what you're asking is not possible or it's not well explained.